# Neptune AWS sortOrder asc and desc don't give reverses of each other

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

I am searching for with `my_table` and I get all the tables I expect, sorted by score (though I am not sure if it's in the correct order since I don't know how to get the scores from elasticsearch).

When I reverse it (i.e. from sortOrder DESC to ASC), I do not get the exact reverse. What is the reason for this?

```
When I search with sortOrder DESC, I get the results [my_table, table_2, my_table].
When I search with sortOrder ASC , I get the results [my_table, my_table, table_2].
Something weird is that I would expect both my_table to be ranked equally and table_2 to be ranked lower but that doesn't seem to be the case based on the ordering.


limit = 100
g.withSideEffect(
    "Neptune#fts.endpoint", f"{url}"
)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.queryType", "query_string")
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.maxResults", limit)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#enableResultCache", enable_cache)
.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.sortOrder", "DESC"). # <- switching this doesn't flip the order
.V()
.hasLabel("table")
.has(
    "*",
    f"Neptune#fts entity_type:"table" AND ({query})",
)
```

Comment: Does this still happen if you remove the results cache?

Comment: From initial poking on one set of results, this seems to be the case, however, I would need to check further to be sure since it could have just been luck.

I checked on elasticsearch and the scoring is definitely different but the ordering isn't consistent with its score so something I set in Neptune is doing something to the score. I'll definitely update though.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you were able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Caching wasn't enabled in the Neptune cluster which caused this behaviour.
The engine being used did not support caching.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer is a bit unclear, especially since in the code you posted in your question, there appears to be a `enable_cache` attribute/parameter used. Perhaps you could elaborate with a code example, or further explanation.